# Telethon: How to upload Channel/Chat Logo?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

How to upload Channel/Chat Logo?  I did not find this information in the official documentation.

Comment: Interestingly, those who put "minus" is generally understood about what speech? Or they have decided that I am in the customer telegram can not understand? Did you guys see the tags? Or do you actually know the answer, but you think I'm a total noob? You know, I spent a lot of time searching for information in the Telethon API, but did not find what I was looking for or did not understand. And I'm sure I'm not alone. Perhaps developers should pay more attention to writing documentation.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code to change avatar of the channel :

i using `EditPhotoRequest` , `InputChatUploadedPhoto` to change avatar of my channel(**test_ali3**).

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import EditPhotoRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputChatUploadedPhoto

api_id = XXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+989XXXXXXXXX'
################################################
channel_username = "test_ali3"
################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash,
                    )
client.start()

channel_entity = client.get_entity(channel_username)
upload_file_result = client.upload_file(file='images/amnesic98.jpg')
input_chat_uploaded_photo = InputChatUploadedPhoto(upload_file_result)
try:
   result = client(EditPhotoRequest(channel=channel_entity, 
photo=input_chat_uploaded_photo))
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)

print('finish')
```